# JS - for each anchor link with specific URL in string, replace anchor link with its text

Tags: javascript, jquery

To give an example of what I want, imagine this string:

```
$text = 'lorem ipsum <a href="/s/about">About us</a> lorem ipsum';
```

If this string contains an anchor link that has an href that starts with `/`, replace the entire anchor link with only its inner text. The result of this function would return the following:

> lorem ipsum About us lorem ipsum

I've adapted a function I've used in the past for this purpose:

```
function replaceAnyQueriedElementByItsText(markup, selector) {
  const doc = (new DOMParser)
    .parseFromString(markup, "text/html");

  doc
    .body
    .querySelectorAll(selector)
    .forEach(node => node
      .parentNode
      .replaceChild(
        document.createTextNode(node.text),
        node,
      )
    );

  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}
```

The problem with this is that this expects a selector, such as a class. But what I want to select only anchors that have a specific href. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Upvote for using DOMParser. What a relief compared to the usual question to do this with regex ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `a[href^="/"]` as selector. So as an argument to your function, it would be:

```
replaceAnyQueriedElementByItsText(markup, 'a[href^="/"]');
```

Example:

```js
function replaceAnyQueriedElementByItsText(markup, selector) {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(markup, "text/html");

  doc.body.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(node => 
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(
        document.createTextNode(node.text),
        node,
    )
  );

  return doc.body.innerHTML;
}

// Example:
let markup = 'lorem ipsum <a href="/s/about">About us</a> lorem ipsum';
let stripped = replaceAnyQueriedElementByItsText(markup, 'a[href^="/"]');
console.log(stripped);
```